# Full Customize google sso button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

i wrote flowing code to auth user by google sso,
but when i used google api, it push their iframe in my code and spoils the style of my project!!
Does anyone know a way to define a separate button like the code below and when it is clicked, the google sso auth page will open for the user?

```
const googleSSO = (e: { preventDefault: () => void }) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(google);
    // google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById('singInDiv'), {
    //   theme: 'outline',
    //   size: 'large',
    //   type: 'icon'
    // });
    return google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id:
        'myclientID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      callback: handleCallbackResponse
    });
  };
 
  return (
    <>
      <IconButton sx={{ ml: 1, mb: 0.5 }} onClick={googleSSO} color="primary">
        <GoogleIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton sx={{ ml: 1, mb: 0.5 }} onClick={googleSSO} color="primary">
        <GitHubIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton sx={{ ml: 1, mb: 0.5 }} onClick={googleSSO} color="primary">
        <FacebookIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Google probably doesn't _want_ you to be able to do that. If you check the examples under https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#theme, there's variants of the buttons that say "Sign in as Foobar", which will automatically display when Google determines that there is a user logged into Google already. Your buttons would not be able to provide the same functionality.

Comment: but i saw many pages with custom google auth button and which not the one defined by Google

Comment: no i didn't have anything